# Why my simple scala file use snakeyaml can't dump a map as YAML to a file?

Tags: scala, yaml, snakeyaml

I have this simple scala file use snakeyaml:

```
object Main extends App {
var a=Map[String,Object]()
a+=("a"->"b")
println(a("a"))

val yaml=new Yaml()
val fileWriter = new FileWriter("d:\\src\\scala\\yaml.txt")
yaml.dump(a,fileWriter)}
```

I only got this in yaml.txt:

```
!!scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 {}
```

Why isn't this `{a: b}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this happens because SnakeYAML is a Java library and it is not aware of Scala-specific collections. So to dump your Scala-`Map` with the library, you should convert it to a Java-`Map` first. Probably the code like this will help:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

...

yaml.dump(a.asJava,fileWriter)
```

If you want to dump a lot of different Scala collections, you might consider implementing a custom [Representers and Constructors](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers) for them.